# Runtime creation of generic Func<T>

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I need to implement the method:

```
object GetFactory(Type type);
```

This method needs to return a Func<T> where typeparam 'T' is the 'type'.

So, my problem is that I don't know how to create a Func<?> at runtime using reflection. Activator.CreateInstance doesn't work because there are no constructors on delegates.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You use `Delegate.CreateDelegate`, i.e. from a `MethodInfo`; below, I've hard-coded, but you would use some logic, or `Expression`, to get the actual creation method:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
class Foo {}

static class Program
{
    static Func<T> GetFactory<T>()
    {
        return (Func<T>)GetFactory(typeof(T));
    }
    static object GetFactory(Type type)
    {
        Type funcType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(type);
        MethodInfo method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("CreateFoo",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
        return Delegate.CreateDelegate(funcType, method);
    }
    static Foo CreateFoo() { return new Foo(); }
    static void Main()
    {
        Func<Foo> factory = GetFactory<Foo>();
        Foo foo = factory();
    }
}
```

For non-static methods, there is an overload of `Delegate.CreateDelegate` that accepts the target instance.

Comment: Mark, I don't actually know what T is.  If I knew what T is, this would be easy.

Comment: I modified the question to better state my problem.

Comment: Not exactly what I needed , but this pushed me down the right path.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oooh, was playing with reflection the other day and wondered if there was a way to describe a generic type definition in code, and now I know: List<>, which presumably can only appear inside typeof?

Comment: @Earwicker: correct; you simply omit all the type-args - for example, KeyValuePair<,> instead of KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>

Answer (score 1):

I use this with generics in EF Core including making Expression<Func<SomeModelType,bool>> for let's say a Where clause, you can chain MakeGenericType calls with nested generics.

```
var someType = SomeDbContext.SomeDataModelExample.GetType();
var funcType1 = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { someType });
var result = Activator.CreateInstance(funcType1);
var result2 = Activator.CreateInstance(funcType1, someParams);
```

Comment: I use this with generics in EF Core including making Expression<Func<SomeModelType,bool>> for let's say a Where clause, you can chain MakeGenericType calls with nested generics.

Answer (score 0):

I think the usual approach would be to make the "dumb" version be the thing that you spoof at runtme, and then provide a helper extension method to provide the type-safe version on top of it.

Comment: So, this is in the bowels of an IoC container, and I have to return the object as a strongly typed dependency, not necessarily knowing that what was requested was a Func<T> (it could be a Uri or string).

Answer (score 0):

you could create Expression objects instead of a func, and compile() the expression to get a Func delegate.