# Run-time generated TResult for Func<T,TResult>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

There is an external generic method, which I call with reflection. But there is a trick: this method has a following signature – `Foo<TResult>(Func<Bar, TResult> factory)`. The problem is that in my method, I get `TResult` not as generic type, but dynamically, during run-time. Actually, there is a whole purpose of my method – being dynamic.
I tried following code as parameter for my reflected `Foo`:

```
Func<Bar, dynamic> factory = (bar) =>
{
    return tResultInstance;
};
```

Yes, I actually don't need `Bar`, it is not a mistake. :) Problem is that when I invoking my reflected `Foo` it fails with casting exception, because it cannot cast `System.Object` to `TResult`.

So, is that possible to dynamically (during run-time) create such Func to pass it to dynamical invocation?

**UPD 0.**

*Static.*

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddScoped<Baz>(_ => new Baz("string"));
```

*Dynamic.*

```
private const string AddScopedMethodName = "AddScoped";
private const string AddScopedMethodSignature = "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection AddScoped[TService](Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, System.Func`2[System.IServiceProvider,TService])";

<...>

var bazConstructorInfo = bazType.GetConstructor(new Type[1] // bazType is Baz.
{
    typeof(String)
});
var bazConstructorParameters = new object[1]
{
    inputString // inputString is "string".
};
var bazInstance = bazConstructorInfo.Invoke(bazConstructorParameters);

var addScopedMethodInfo = typeof(ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions)
    .GetMethods()
    .Where(method =>
        method.IsPublic &&
        method.IsGenericMethod &&
        (method.Name == AddScopedMethodName) &&
        (method.ToString() == AddScopedMethodSignature))
    .Single();
var addScopedMethod = addScopedMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(bazType);
Func<IServiceProvider, dynamic> implementationFactory = (serviceProvider) =>
{
    return bazInstance;
};
var addScopedMethodParameters = new object[2]
{
    services, // services is IServiceCollection.
    implementationFactory
};
addScopedMethod.Invoke(
    services,
    addScopedMethodParameters); // Fails with "Object of type 'System.Func`2[System.IServiceProvider,System.Object]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Func`2[System.IServiceProvider,Baz]'." exception. :(
```

**UPD 1.**

To @alexei-levenkov.
It looks like [Runtime creation of generic Func<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658316/runtime-creation-of-generic-funct) is not answer to me. They are using following code:

```
static Foo CreateFoo() { return new Foo(); }

<...>

var method = typeof(Program)
    .GetMethod(
        "CreateFoo",
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
```

But in my case, I do not know `Foo` before runtime. I just cannot write this `static Foo CreateFoo() { return new Foo(); }` line.

Comment: Then show us how you are calling the method via reflection.

Comment: Please add an [mre], cause now it is not very clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @DavidG, I updated my question. Sorry that I posted it incomplete.

Comment: @guru-stron, I updated my question. Sorry that I posted it incomplete.

Comment: I'm pretty sure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658316/runtime-creation-of-generic-funct is what you are looking for. Please confirm so the question can be closed as duplicate. Or [edit] to explain why it is not the case.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, wrote "UPD 1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick fix would be adding helper class:

```
class Helper
{
    public static Func<IServiceProvider, T> GetFactory<T>(T instance) => _ => instance;
}
```

And using it to get implementation factory:

```
var methodInfo = typeof(Helper).GetMethod(nameof(Helper.GetFactory));
var implementationFactory = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(bazType).Invoke(null, new[] { bazInstance });
```

But in general all of this seems a huge overkill when you can just use [`ServiceDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicedescriptor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) directly:

```cs
Func<IServiceProvider, object> implementationFactory = _ => bazInstance;
var serviceDescriptor = new ServiceDescriptor(bazType, implementationFactory, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
services.Add(serviceDescriptor);
```

Also the instance creation reflection can be reduced to [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=net-6.0#system-activator-createinstance(system-type-system-object())) call:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
Type bazType = typeof(Baz);
var bazConstructorParameters = new object[]
{
    "string" // inputString is "string".
};
var bazInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(bazType, bazConstructorParameters);
Func<IServiceProvider, object> implementationFactory = _ => bazInstance;
var serviceDescriptor = new ServiceDescriptor(bazType, implementationFactory, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
services.Add(serviceDescriptor);
```